# FDT, Compile css to swf

Tags: eclipse, flash, apache-flex, fdt

I am looking into using FDT (I currently use FB4), downloaded the free eclipse plugin, version 5.0, and configured it.  I was trying to figure out how to compile a css to a swf file with it. This is super simple in Flash Builder, e.g. right click the css file and choose *Compile CSS to SWF*. I looked around and there is info on doing it via command line etc. Is there a way to do this in FDT eclipse plugin?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, FDT does not currently support this feature. If it does I'll will update it here.